# Getting can not resolve 'PhoneAuthCredential' symbol

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using `Firebase` Phone Authentication in my app. I have added all `Gradle` configuration like in app and in project using `Firebase` Assistant.
The `Gradle` file look like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1"
```

But still getting can not resolve 'PhoneAuthCredential' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a newer version of the firebase-auth library.

Check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#before-you-begin) on Phone Number Authentication. The latest version is 11.6.0, and from the [Google Play Services Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_2017_-_version_110) it looks like Phone authentication features weren't added until version 11.

Comment: Getting could not find 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0' after adding it and rebuilding it.

Comment: Do you have the [google maven repository](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven) listed in your project gradle file?

Comment: how to add this

Comment: The directions are in the page I linked to in the comments above. Should be something like this: 

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}`

Comment: Great. Accept the answer if you think it may help others.